# Блокировка и пропуск заблокированных записей в MariaDB

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, mariadb, typeorm

**ORM** - TypeORM;
**DB** - MariaDB.

В базе данных есть 2 записи, которые соответствуют условию запроса. Если мы запускаем два параллельных запроса, то первый запрос блокирует обе строки и возвращает одну, в то время как второй запрос возвращает `null`.

Хотелось бы иметь возможность блокировать только одну (возвращаемую) строку, чтобы избежать такой ситуации.

```js
const queryRunner : QueryRunner = this.connect.createQueryRunner();
await queryRunner.connect();
await queryRunner.startTransaction();
const identificationProcess = await queryRunner.manager
            .getRepository(IdentificationProcessEntity)
            .createQueryBuilder("identification_process")
            .orderBy("identification_process.updated_at", "ASC")
            .where("identification_process.status = :status", { status: IdentificationStatusEnum.Scanning })
            .useTransaction(true)
            .setLock("pessimistic_write")
            .setOnLocked("skip_locked")
            .take(1)
            .getOne()
```